# Procmail seems not being executed when fetching emails with fetchmail

Tags: linux, email, mutt, procmail

I have the following problem:
I got a new working PC (Debian testing, codenme: stretch) recently and had to reinstall `fetchmail` and `procmail` in order to read my emails with `mutt`.
Now, `fetchmail` works well as also `mutt` is doing, only the spool mailbox of my mails seems to stay the same default one, which is `/var/mail/user`.

In my `.fetchmailrc` I defined the `mda` that should be executed with:

`mda '/usr/bin/procmail -f %F -d %T';`

and the `.procmailrc` that I created looks like this:

```
# Please check if all the paths in PATH are reachable, remove the ones that
# are not.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/ucb:/bin:/usr/local/bin:.
MAILDIR=$HOME/Mail  # Youd better make sure it exists
SPOOL=$HOME/Mail/mbox
DEFAULT=$MAILDIR/mbox
ORGMAIL=$MAILDIR/mbox
LOGFILE=$MAILDIR/log        
LOCKFILE=$HOME/.lockmail
VERBOSE= yes
LOGABSTRACT= all
```

After looking everywhere I could, changeing and checking the permissions of the `rc` files and of the mail folder again and again, finally trying to uninstall all and reinstalling it, nothing changed: the mails are all still delivered to `/var/mail/user` even when I insert some delivery conditions into the `.procmailrc`.

Finally I noticed that there is no `/etc/procmailrc` file (as, I think, it is supposed to be) and also all the `log` files that are supposed to exist and to be written are not existent.

`fetchmail` is calling procmail, because a `$ fetchmail -vvv` with an incoming email has, within it's longer output, this string:

```
fetchmail: about to deliver with: /usr/bin/procmail -f 'email@addres' -d 'user'
```

My conclusion is that `procmail` isn't working properly or at all.
The emails still arrive, but all in that default mailbox/folder and I'm not able to move them while they are delivered (when I'm in `mutt` I'm able to save them to all the mailboxes I have or might define).

I would really appreciate if someone could help me solving this issue!

Kind regards.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  For troubleshooting a system service, I suggest migrating to [sf] or perhaps [unix.se] -- you can flag for moderator attention and request migration yourself (us regulars can really only vote to close, or to suggest moving to the [sf] migration queue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LOCKFILE` assignment prevents Procmail from doing anything at all.

Examining Procmail's output on standard error with `procmail -m VERBOSE=yes .procmailrc </dev/null` should readily reveal that it is forever waiting on the lock, and eventually giving up.

See also http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#locking and http://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html

Generally, you should not need to touch `ORGMAIL` for any reason, either.

Procmail doesn't require an `/etc/procmailrc` file; if it does exist, it will be invoked before your `.procmailrc`, but it should not be necessary or particularly useful in your scenario.

Normally your `.procmailrc` should exist in your home directory, with read (and, for practical maintenance reasons, write) access only for yourself.  Depending on how `fetchmail` runs `procmail`, there could be circumstances which are not clear from your question -- for example, if `fetchmail` is neither running as `root` nor as yourself, it might not have permission to switch to your UID.

For troubleshooting, maybe move your regular `.procmailrc` to the side and try a really simple, general one which perhaps simply assigns `LOGFILE=/tmp/procmail-testing.log` and quits, with read permission for everyone.  If you can get that to work, maybe `` LOG=`whoami` `` so you can see what permissions it's running with.

Comment: I commented the `LOCKFILE` line. Procmail's standard error output are the expected lines from http://porkmail.org/era/mail/procmail-debug.html . a `fetchmail -vvv` now has another line: `procmail: Couldn't read "/home/user/.procmailrc"` and indeed a `procmail -v` has in its output this line: `Your system mailbox: /var/mail/user`. I did check the permissions of the `.procmailrc` again, but they are the same as in the man.

Comment: So your `.procmailrc` is in the wrong location or has the wrong permissions.  The system mailbox simply tells you the system default, i.e. before any `.procmailrc` (which clearly could not be read anyway).

Comment: Yes, that's true, I realized in the moment I sent the comment... I added the `-m $HOME/.procmailrc` flag to the `mda` call in the `.fetchmailrc` and now procmail seems to work. (the emails are bounced somewhere I don't know, but this is a mailbox and procmail syntax problem, I think...) Thank you for your help!

Comment: If this answer helped, please consider accepting, so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers -- thanks!

Comment: Not entirely convinced `-m` makes more sense than `-d` here but it also depends on `fetchmail`, which I'm not terribly familiar with.

Comment: I don't know why now it is working, while before it wasn't, also because it is the first time that I see the `-m` called in the `.fetchmailrc`, but as long as it is working I leave it like that...